# Почему-то не создается файл логирования spring

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

Есть файл log4j2.xml, который размещен в resources с настройками:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" packages="ru">
<Properties>
    <Property name="filename">logs/test.log</Property>
</Properties>
<ThresholdFilter level="trace"/>
<Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="${filename}">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d [On Line: %L] [Method: %M] %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="error"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

В одном из классе пишу

```
private static Logger _log = LogManager.getLogger();
...
_log.info("something");
```

Но файл логов не создается совсем. Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1):

[Здесь](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging) посмотрите. Spring Framework использует Commons Logging для логирования своих действий и штатно может быть связан только в log4j и slf4j. Вы же используете log4j2 - тут нужны специальные танцы с бубном. Например, как [здесь](https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-xml/).